# How to get current time in c

Tags: c

```
void takeTime(struct tm * timeNow)
{
    time_t timeInSec;
    time(&timeInSec);

    timeNow = localtime(&timeInSec);    
    return;
}

int main() 
{
    struct tm* timeNow;
    takeTime(timeNow);
    printf("%s\n", asctime(timeNow));
    return 0;
}
```

tried executing the code, but got Segmentation fault, can anyone explain why. i'm new to programming!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `timeNow`. There's no need to use a pointer, just declare `struct tm timeNow;` and use `&timeNow` when calling the other functions.

Comment: MSVC has a list of various [time management functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/time-management?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `localtime` returns a pointer to a statically allocated structure.

The code in the question modifies the local copy of the pointer `timeNow` in `takeTime` but the value is not returned to the caller.

If you want to pass the pointer to the caller you need to emulate a reference by using another level of indirection, i.e. a pointer to a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void takeTime(struct tm ** timeNow)
{
    time_t timeInSec;
    time(&timeInSec);

    *timeNow = localtime(&timeInSec);    
    // This return at the end of a void function can be removed
    // return;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct tm* timeNow;
    takeTime(&timeNow);
    printf("%s\n", asctime(timeNow));
    return 0;
}
```

Or you could want to get a copy of this structure. Then you need a structure variable in `main` and have to pass its address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void takeTime(struct tm * timeNow)
{
    time_t timeInSec;
    time(&timeInSec);

    *timeNow = *localtime(&timeInSec);    
    // This return at the end of a void function can be removed
    // return;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct tm timeNow;
    takeTime(&timeNow);
    printf("%s\n", asctime(&timeNow));
    return 0;
}
```

Or you could return the pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct tm * takeTime(void)
{
    time_t timeInSec;
    time(&timeInSec);

    return localtime(&timeInSec);    
}

int main() 
{
    struct tm* timeNow;
    timeNow = takeTime();
    printf("%s\n", asctime(timeNow));
    return 0;
}
```

Another variant of returning a structure and a more detailed explanation were shown in an Farhod Nematov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75074210/10622916), which unfortunately has been deleted.